# Get the string from known index till \r\n is found

Tags: c#, string

I have a string `s` which reads my batch file content.
Suppose the content of `s` is as follows:

```
"\t\r\n@@echo off\r\necho \"Hello World!!!\"\r\necho \"One\"\r\nset /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...\r\ncall second.bat\r\necho \"done!!!\"\r\ncall third.bat\r\necho \"done 3!!!\""
```

i want to write a condition which does the below,

```
while (s.Contains("call")) && (if string next to "call" contains(.bat))
```

how to acheive this?
I am new to c#. Please help me in this regard.
thanks in advance

Comment: Because you are new in c# I would suggest to read some tutorials and documentation. For example this: [Manipulating Strings in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/manipulating-strings).

Comment: It is not clear from the wording of your question _"Get the string from known index till \r\n is found"_ & the condition _"while (s.Contains("call")) && (if string next to "call" contains(.bat))"_ exactly what you are trying to achieve. Instead of reading the batch file into a string - it may be better to read it line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the string on new lines and process only the lines you want as follows:

```
foreach (string line in s.Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.None).Where(x => x.ToLower().StartsWith("call") && x.ToLower().EndsWith(".bat")))
{
    // do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `s.Split(new[] { "\r", "\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)`?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are *parsing* some kind of log; in this case I suggest using *regular expressions*, e.g.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

string source =
  "\t\r\n@@echo off\r\necho \"Hello World!!!\"\r\necho \"One\"\r\nset /p DUMMY=Hit ENTER to continue...\r\ncall second.bat\r\necho \"done!!!\"\r\ncall third.bat\r\necho \"done 3!!!\"";

var matches = Regex
  .Matches(source, @"call.+?\.bat", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
  .OfType<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value);

// call second.bat
// call third.bat
foreach (string match in matches) {
  ...
}
```

It's unclear what is "string next", in the code above I've treated it as "after". In case it means "after several *white spaces*" the pattern will be

```
.Matches(source, @"call\s+?\.bat", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my mind is using the `text.Split ('\n', '\r')` method. This way you get an array of strings which are separated by those line break symbols. Because you'd get empty strings, you should also filter those out. For that, I would recommend converting the array to a list, iterate through all elements and remove all empty strings (consider using `string.IsNullOrEmpty (text)`).

If you always have `\r\n`, you can use `text.Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.None)` instead, and don't have to worry about empty strings in between. You could still convert it to a list for easier use.

Then you would get a fine list of the entire content separated through line breaks. Now you could loop through that and do whatever you want.